# Get data from component to component? (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have an angular application with an webapi backend. In my "home component" i show some street names. Now when I click on one of these names, i want to show a detailed table of the house numbers in this street.

app.component.html:

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let street of streets">
    <td (click)="getInfosOfStreet(street)">{{street}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now when i click on a row i get the corret data with this method:

app.component.ts:

```
getInfosOfStreet(street):void{
    this.orderService.getStreetInfos(street).subscribe(data=>{
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

But now i want to show this data in another page (component).

street-info.component.html:

```
<h1>Hausnummern</h1>
<br>
<button>Zur Hauptseite</button>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is that i do not really know how to get this data from the home component to the new component. I want to store this data in an array and display it in this table in the street-info.component.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reproduce the Angular JS .broadcast() / .on() behaviour in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60154267/how-can-i-reproduce-the-angular-js-broadcast-on-behaviour-in-angular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yuri answer is right. But I am adding my 2 cents as well.

In the end it depends wether the component where you want to show this data is a child of the current where you retrieve the data or a totally different one.

As I experienced Angular being service oriented, i would suggest to use a small service for that kind of information exchange and use the observer pattern.

like so:

create a **street-info.service.ts** file with `ng g s street-info`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class StreetInfoService {

    streetObs$: Subject<any>; // your street-data type
    streetData: any;


    constructor() {
        this.streetObs$ = new Subject();
    }

    getStreetObs(): Observable<any> {
        return this.streetObs$.asObservable();
    }

    setStreetObs(data: any) {
        this.streetData = data;
        this.streetObs$.next(data);
    }

    getStreetData() {
        return this.streetData;
    }
}
```

In your getInfosOfStreet() method (inject the service into the constructor of your component to use it):

```
getInfosOfStreet(street):void{
    this.orderService.getStreetInfos(street).subscribe(data=>{
      console.log(data);
      this.streetInfoService.setStreetObs(data); // here you can send the data to your service and let observers of the streetInfoObservable get notified.
    });
  }
```

Now in your street-info.component.ts you can subscribe to that observable like so:

```
unsubscribe$: Subject<void>;
streetData: any; // or an array of whatever type you need

constructor(private streetInfoService: StreetInfoService) {
  this.unsubscribe$ = new Subject(); // You need this subject to notify on destroy to unsubscribe from the subscription to prevent memory-leaks
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.streetData = this.streetInfoService.getStreetData();
  // and here subscribe to the observable
  this.streetInfoService.getStreetObs().pipe(
    takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
  ).subscribe(streetData => {

    // if its an object
    this.streetData = streetData;

    // if its an array do something like this
    this.streetData = [...streetData]; // I am using the spread operator here

  })
}

// here you unsubscribe from the observables
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.unsubscribe$.next();
  this.unsubscribe$.complete();
}
```

But it really depends on the structure of your app. If the `<app-street-info>` is a child of the view retrieving the data or they have the same parent, using an @Input() and passing the data from parent to child would be enough.

Regards.

Comment: ah okay, now i understand. Thanks for your detailed and useful answer!

Comment: np, you are welcome. Just let me know if there is more help u need.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how both of your components are composed in your application. Assuming the `app.component.html` contains also a `<app-street-info>` you can simply use an [@angular/core/EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter).

In the your `street-info.component.ts` handles the notifications emitted by `app.component.ts`. Study the example in the link.